# converting a auto_ptr to a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

How can I change an std::auto_ptr  to a boost::shared_ptr?  Here are my restrictions:
1.  I am using an API class, lets call it only_auto that returns these pointers 
2.  I need to use the call in auto_only
3.  My semantics involves sharing  so I do need to use a  shared_ptr)
4.  In class only_auto operator = is private to prevent coping 
5.  Also a only_auto object must be made by a cloning call  std::auto_ptr creat_only_auto();

I know of template explicit shared_ptr(std::auto_ptr & r); but how do I use it in this scenario?

A super-simplified code example:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>
    #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

    using namespace std;

    class only_auto
    {
      public:
      static auto_ptr<only_auto> create_only_auto();
      void func1();
      void func2();
      //and lots more functionality

      private:
      only_auto& operator = (const only_auto& src);
    };

    class sharing_is_good : public only_auto
    {
      static boost::shared_ptr<only_auto> create_only_auto()
      {
        return boost::shared_ptr (only_auto::create_only_auto()); //not the correct call but ...
      }

    };

    int main ()
    {
       sharing_is_good x;

       x.func1();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `shared_ptr` constructor is declared as:

```
template<class Other>
shared_ptr(auto_ptr<Other>& ap);
```

Note that it takes a non-const lvalue reference.  It does this so that it can correcly release the `auto_ptr`'s ownership of the object.

Because it takes a non-const lvalue reference, you cannot call this member function with an rvalue, which is what you are trying to do:

```
return boost::shared_ptr(only_auto::create_only_auto());
```

You'll need to store the result of `only_auto::create_only_auto()` in a variable, then pass that variable to the `shared_ptr` constructor:

```
std::auto_ptr<only_auto> p(only_auto::create_only_auto());
return boost::shared_ptr<only_auto>(p);
```

Comment: I think this solution is overly complex

Answer (score 1):

> `3. My semantics involves sharing so I do need to use a shared_ptr)`

Most valid uses of auto_ptr are source compatible with std::unique_ptr, so you might want to look at converting to that. If everything builds okay then you're safe. (You might want to move to using a typedef if you're not already, so you can easily change the type in the future.) If you have a compile error you may have a bug in your code where you were previously using an invalidated auto_ptr.

I think you should only look to moving to std::shared_ptr after you've validated things with unique_ptr and you see you really do need shared ownership (often you can just use unique ownership and non-owning pointers).

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
return boost::shared_ptr<only_auto>(only_auto::create_only_auto().release());
```

should do the trick